# AlertDialog with a list

Tags: android

I created a alertDialog with a list, but for me keeps indoors.

```
public class Day extends ListFragment{
private final int IDD_LIST_TIMES = 1; 
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
String[] times = { "09:00", "15:00",  "19:00", "20:00", "23:00" };
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 TimeAdapter myListAdapter = new TimeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.text_fragment, times);
setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
 lv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) { case android.R.id.list:
                        showDialog(IDD_LIST_TIMES);
                        break;
            }}
       });
       return rootView;
    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) { case IDD_LIST_TIMES:
            final String[] mTimes = {"for 5 minutes", "for 10 minutes", "for 15 minutes"};
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Alarm clock"); 
            builder.setItems(mTimes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Alarm clock " + mTimes[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }});
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            return builder.create();
            default:
            return null;
        }
       }
       }
```

but an error appears constantly for me, where red line "new AlertDialog.Builder(this)"
Why? Prompt me, how  to write.

Comment: `this` refers to `ListFragment` which extends `Fragment`, which is not a context. There are a lot of things wrong with your class.

Comment: how is it correct to write? prompt me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a `spinner` as `dialog` you can use below code in XML:

```
<Spinner android:spinnerMode="dropdown" ... />
```

OR

if you are doing programatically then use:

```
Spinner sp = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
```

OR

If you want to display an ListActivity as Dialog the put this code in your `Manifest` file:

```
   <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use wrong context object i.e. 'this' which is not applicable for "new AlertDialog.Builder(this)"

First, get the application context in onCreate method and store it into local variable. Use local variable instead of "this" in "new AlertDialog.Builder(this)"

Declare variable 
    private Context mContext = null;

initialize it in your OnCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Use it in your method
    "new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)"

Hope this will solve your problem.